# Improve memory-inefficient script

Tags: matlab, loops, image-processing, memory

I have to create a probabilistic voxel map from 5 individual maps which are binary maps containing either 1 or 0. Let's call these individual maps **X1, X2, x3, X4, X5**. To get the probabilistic map I do `Y = (X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5)/5`. Thus, each voxel will give me the percentage of individual maps having 1 as its value for that voxel. For instance, if value of a voxel in Y is 0.4, that tells me that 40% of the individual maps (2 individual maps) have 1 as value for that particular voxel. The issue I have is that when the number of individual maps increases, my script becomes very bulky. This is what I have

```
maindir=<where my individual maps are>
P={};
subj={'subj1','subj2','subj3','subj4','subj5'}

for a = 1:length(subj)
   indv_roi=spm_select('FPList',fullfile(maindir),sprintf('^%s.*\\.img$',subj{a}));
   P.(subj{a}) = spm_read_vols(spm_vol(indv_roi),1);
   P.(subj{a})(isnan(P.(subj{a})))=0;
end

Y = (P.subj1+P.subj2+P.subj3+P.subj4+P.subj5)/5
```

Clearly this is very inefficient. Does anyone have a suggestion how to improve my code? Thank you.

Comment: can you profile it to see what are the time consuming lines?

Comment: I actually don't know how to do this. Would you mind showing me how?

Comment: In the matlab GUI, click "HOME" then click "Run and Time"  Now, run your script from there, and figure out where things are slow.

Comment: Apart from my answer (below), another general tip: You're increasing the size of `P` dynamically, which is quite inefficient and should be avoided in MATLAB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume memory is your bottleneck?

Instead of loading all the images into memory *and then* calculating the average, you could add the voxel maps in the loop and normalise in the end. That way, only one image needs to be in memory at any given point:

```
Y = init_empty_volume()

subj={'subj1','subj2','subj3','subj4','subj5'}

for a = 1:length(subj)
   indv_roi=spm_select('FPList',fullfile(maindir),sprintf('^%s.*\\.img$',subj{a}));

   X = spm_read_vols(spm_vol(indv_roi),1);
   X(isnan(X))=0;

   Y = Y + X;

end

Y = Y ./ length(subj)
```

With `init_empty_volume()` I mean either initialising an empty matrix with the right dimensions, or loading an example image and multiplying by zero, whatever is easier in your case.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helps.